# Extend background-color with Django templates inserts

Tags: html, css, django

Sorry my Django lingo is not up to par, I am just starting to learn the whole framework. I have my base.html defined with all of my CSS and JS deceleration and the standard layout of my site.

It contains my

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

where I can insert my other templates like index.html. However if I insert index.html the content will make the page larger then 100% of the screen height, so when we scroll down the background color I set with base.html does not extend to cover all of the background of index.html.

I declared base.html background with some CSS

```
#baseBody{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I can get the hight to extend pass that if I set it to >100% but I want to set it "dynamically" so that it covers whatever templates throw at it.

Answer (score 0):

While it sounds like the issues you're having might be cause by HTML/CSS, I think you might also be misunderstanding the Django template system. If, for instance you're coming from a php background, you'd include your required file:

```
include('/path/to/some_file.php');
```

With Django, however, (while you can indeed include other template files if the need exists) you extend other templates. So you could have a 'base.html' file which would contain anything you consider to be global across an application, such as a header or footer. Then, you could have another template file used for this particular view, say, 'page.html'. In your view, you'd render the 'page.html' file which would extend your 'base.html' using:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

This approach helps to keep your view logic contained in your views rather your templates, and let's the Django template engine render templates a bit more efficiently

Comment: That is what I though, I couldn't find any other place that had my problems so I wasn't 100% sure how Django extends it's template files. Thank you